# man page generation/packaging/installation with cmake

Tags: cmake, manpage

I am looking for some good examples / tutorials on how to generate, package, and install man pages in projects using CMake.

Answer (score 7):

With cmake 2.8.12 under Linux, the following works for me:

```
ADD_CUSTOM_TARGET(man ALL)

ADD_CUSTOM_COMMAND(
  TARGET man
  SOURCE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/myprog.pod
  COMMAND pod2man ARGS -s 1 -c "myprog manual" ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/myprog.pod ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/myprog.1
  OUTPUTS ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/myprog.1
)

ADD_CUSTOM_COMMAND(
  TARGET man
  SOURCE man
  DEPENDS ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/myprog.1
)

INSTALL(FILES ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/myprog.1 DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/man/man1)
```

Which looks unelegant even by CMake standards. I would like to see a solution with less stammering.

Comment: I realise this answer is +1yr old, but because it pops on Google search results, I feel compelled to share that this method issues warnings on CMake >=3.2.2 due to policy CMP0050.
The CMake mailing list suggests a way to do what the asker wants:
http://www.cmake.org/pipermail/cmake/2010-September/039781.html

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you would be interested in the following solution, which allows to generate and install man pages, written in Markdown or AsciiDoc:

https://github.com/rnpgp/cmake-modules/

To generate and install man page, written in Markdown, it would be as easy as add two lines to your `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
include(PandocMan)
add_pandoc_man("${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/utility.1.md")
```

The same with AsciiDoc and AsciiDoctor:

```
include(AdocMan)
add_adoc_man("${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/utility.1.adoc")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can delve into the source tree of CMake itself to see how it installs its own man pages.

It is sure to be a combination of:

- using CMake's add_custom_command
- calling tools to produce/generate documentation in those custom commands
- installing the results in the correct location

See the documentation for CMake's add_custom_command and install commands for more information:

- http://cmake.org/cmake/help/cmake-2-8-docs.html#command:add_custom_command
- http://cmake.org/cmake/help/cmake-2-8-docs.html#command:install